# Deinitialize multiple spinlocks

Tags: c, synchronization, spinlock

My application has `N` lists and each of this lists is protected by a separate spinlock. I'm working on the code responsible for deinitialization and I am wondering whether is there a way implement it without an additional synchronization than these `N` spinlocks.

The first solution which came to my mind is obviously wrong because destroying the lock which is being held is an undefined behavior

```
// This code doesn't work
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    spinlock_lock(app_ctx->lock[i]);

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    spin_destroy(app_ctx->lock[i]);
```

My second idea is additional "management" lock:

```
spinlock_lock(app_ctx->management_lock);

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    spin_destroy(app_ctx->lock[i]);

spinlock_unlock(app_ctx->management_lock);
```

but all the threads that try to access lists will have to hold `management_lock` which (from performance point of view) is far from optimal solution.

Is there any pattern for deinitializing set of spinlocks safely without big impact on the performance?

Comment: If you don't have some other mechanism to ensure that they aren't being used when you try to destroy, how do you know another thread wouldn't try to lock after you've destroyed? Also, as a side note, is a spinlock definitely the right choice for you (as opposed to say a non-spinning mutex)?

Comment: My app might be used in linux kernel and it has to work in the interrupt context, so unfortunately I can't use mutexes.

Comment: That's a very fair reason, but I asked anyways just in case. The rest of my comment does still apply.